# Renconsile error on Odoo server

Tags: odoo-9

[![Odoo error][1]][1]

I get the below error when i try to reconcile my bank in Odoo 9.
when i click the bank button it does not reconcile

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgLmT.png
Gwtting an error when i try to renconsile odoo bank.
    Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 650, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 687, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 323, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 966, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 895, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 887, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/odoo/odoo-server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_currency.py", line 252, in get_format_currencies_js_function
    function = "if (arguments[1] === false || arguments[1] === undefined) {" + 
         company_currency_format + " }" + function
            UnboundLocalError: local variable 'company_currency_format' referenced before c 
          assignment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Dear , saw what the issue was by tailing my sever logs.It turns out  i had not assigned an active currency under currency settings.